# Is there any OpenJDK that is fully free and will be available for commercial use

Tags: java

I just recently heard about the licensing for Oracle JDK, after trying to create a springboot app for a year.  I wanted to find out if there are other alternative JDK which are free for production/commercial use, and if they are what is the certainty that it wouldnt be paid for after or that it would be in the market for long. My only alternative now is to rewrite my code in another language.

Comment: The interesting thing is that the [Oracle Java SE FAQs](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/faqs-jsp-136696.html) actually answer this directly:   *"Is Java still free?
The current version of Java - Java SE 11 is available from Oracle under an open source license at http://jdk.java.net/11/."*

Comment: A 10 minutes Devoxx video @ https://youtu.be/cUqcSFLnk_E?t=35 provides good info on free/commercial license, updates and support topics.

Answer (score 19):

## Yes, Java is still free

It is vital that you study: [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-c02aef8c9e04). Written by key members of the Java community, providing both a summary and all the gory details.

## Guidance

The [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) source code is [available free-of-cost](https://openjdk.java.net/) per its GNU GPL+linking exception license.

Several vendors provide releases based on that OpenJDK source code. They can do so free-of-cost or they can charge a fee or set other licensing terms, as long as they abide by the GNU GPL+linking exception licensing.

The Oracle JDK in latest versions has changed its licensing. It can no longer be used in production without a paid support plan. Contact Oracle for details. The Oracle JDK has converged to be at feature-parity with OpenJDK, with Oracle having contributed to OpenJDK even more of their formerly commercial parts such as [Flight Recorder](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328) and [Mission Control](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jmc/).

Other vendors also provide releases with commercial terms, for a product which may contain some OpenJDK code.

And some vendors such as Adoptium with their Eclipse Temurin product (formerly AdoptOpenJDK), Azul Systems with their Zulu product, and Amazon Web Services with their Corretto product, all provide builds of OpenJDK without payment required.

A release may or may not be labeled “Java”. If a vendor want their release to carry the branding “Java”, they must pass rigorous testing for compliance with the Java specifications and abide by Oracle’s terms for using their trademark.

Here is a flowchart that may help guide you in determining how and where to obtain Java 11. Important: This info may be incorrect. You are responsible for studying the details of the license under which you use any software.

*(Note that the diagrams say "Adoptium", which is not a distribution, but instead the organization that produces the distribution called "Eclipse Temurin". See [here](https://adoptium.net/faq.html#temurinName) for more info.)*

---

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

---

[image: Motivations in choosing a vendor for Java]

Comment: fantastic explanation.

Answer (score 0):

All Oracle's OpenJDK's are free, in any environment. The issue arises when you use the Oracle JDK (not with the OpenJDK). Since they are functionally the same since Java 11, there is no need to switch languages.

More details here:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/09/using-java-11-in-production-important-things-to-know/

Comment: but what about updates and support OpenJDK, would that still be available for open JDK?

Comment: And azul has a commercially supported version.

Comment: @Thanus Updates won't be an issue. Still will be free with 99.99% probability otherwise it wouldn't be called the OpenJDK.

Comment: @Thanus: https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-c02aef8c9e04 for more details on the update schedule. Starting with JDK 11 there's even an LTS version.

Comment: But ... if you want "support" (i.e. someone "on the hook" to answer your questions, a *guarantee* that patches will be applied, corporate warm fuzzies, etc), you do need to pay for that.  But that's standard for open source: the software is free (with full dislaimer), but the support costs money, and so does the indemnification.  'Cos someone has to pay the support staff wages, and the liability insurance bill!   TANSTAAFL.

Comment: @StephenC Yeah, if he needs that kind of support you're definitely right. I assumed he was asking if future updates would support the right to use it freely.

Comment: In the comment he said "updates and support".  He may not have meant it ... but he said it.

Comment: so going forward from here, i am presently using oracle jdk 8, which open jdk will you advice me to use ? cause i am plannig to deploy my app on a server and i want it free.  i am more afraid now that if i use an open JDK licensed under another company, they may start charging later on