# Why stick with Java 5? or why migrate?

Tags: java, version

I'm after some advice, I'm a long time dabbler in C# with a reasonable knowledge, I learned C# at Uni but since then I mostly write the odd test program or control or configurator tools for hardware products. I've tried to keep up to date over the last 19 years and use the latest frameworks and generally have benefitted from this.

I have no idea about Java, and would really appreciate some advice from people actually writing code.
Our company uses Java 5 for one of our software platforms, the argument being that it is the last free version for windows and Java 5 does everything we need.

We're trying to port another piece of software from VB6 to this Java 5 platform.

My fear is that we are moving from one outdated platform to another. I would never dream of starting a new project in .net 2.0 for example.

I also worry that our software developer who is a very smart chap but now in his mid 60s is just stuck in his ways. And that persisting with Java 5 and not wanting to move on will not allow us to attract new talented developers to ultimately hand the torch to, and who I would expect would want to keep upto date with the latest stable technologies.

What are we really missing out on by not moving away from Java 5? Are there security concerns or is it just functionality we are missing out on?
Do people still want to develop in Java 5? Do you young go getters out there care about what version of Java a company is using.

Or are my concerns unfounded?

oh and is Java 5 really still free for commercial use?
I read a few articles including this one:

[https://redresscompliance.com/decoding-oracle-java-licensing-java-licensing-changes-2023/#:~:text=Oracle%20Java%20JDK%20versions%201%2D8%20%E2%80%93%20applying%20security%20patch%20211,products%20listed%20in%20schedule%20b](https://redresscompliance.com/decoding-oracle-java-licensing-java-licensing-changes-2023/#:%7E:text=Oracle%20Java%20JDK%20versions%201%2D8%20%E2%80%93%20applying%20security%20patch%20211,products%20listed%20in%20schedule%20b).

The table (about a 3rd of the way down) suggested that all versions 1 - 8 require a license.

I have had a bit of a look through the forum but cannot find any thing recent enough to be relevant on the subject.

Comment: "*My fear is that we are moving from one outdated platform to another.*" - This is exactly what you are doing. Java 5's EOL was in 2009. To my knowledge, neither Azul nor Red Hat (two prominent members in the java community) provide any support for java 5.

Comment: This questions is probably opinion based and as such likely off topic on this site. I can tell you that staying with Java 5 is incredible risky from a security standpoint, and missing all the good stuff between 5 and 8 at least which is a lot. Only Oracle Java 8+ not free(don't remember the exact update but it must be in the article you linked). However all OpenJDK releases are free. There are several distributions of OpenJDK (Eclipse, Amazon, Redhat, etc) that you can use. Using Java 5 for new projects today is just insane. Java 8 is still Ok for a few years. This is just my personal opinion.

Comment: For new projects I would consider going directly to the latest long term support (LTS) JDK available.

Comment: The article you linked describes licensing for Oracle JDK (Note: Oracle JDK 17 binaries are free to use in production and free to redistribute, at no cost, under the Oracle No-Fee Terms and Conditions). But, as mentioned above, there are multiple, free to use JDK distributions.

Comment: I was worried this might be off topic but I was though I would get some honest and reasoned answers on here compared to the more generic forums that often descent into arguments. I Appreciate the feedback from you all.

Comment: Given all of this, I wonder if it may be worth asking (politely) for a citation for Java 5 being the "last free version." Maybe it was based on a faulty assumption that nobody has questioned up 'til now. I hope you can get the ball rolling for updating the java version. I don't envy your situation...

Comment: I've never understood why some people use older _Java_ versions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your team *really* should read this: [*Java Is Still Free 3.0.0 (Oct 2021)*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-3-0-0-ocrt-2021-bca75c88d23b).

Comment: Related: [*Is there any OpenJDK that is fully free and will be available for commercial use*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54282556/642706)

Answer (score 4):

> What are we really missing out on by not moving away from Java 5?

Lots of new language and standard library features, including some really significant ones (e.g. lambdas and streams).  Lots of third-party software that depends on the newer features.  Technological improvements in the JVM.  Bug fixes in the JVM, standard library, and third-party libraries.

> Are there security concerns or is it just functionality we are missing out on?

I am not aware that any version of Java was 100% free of security issues.  And there are bugs that do not (directly) have security implications, which I don't care to lump in with "functionality".

> Do people still want to develop in Java 5?

Your guy does.  He might not be unique in the world in that respect.  But I am not aware of any subculture of Java developers who are interested in programming specifically and only for Java 5.

> Do you young go getters out there care about what version of Java a company is using.

I'm not exactly young, but thanks.

If I'm buying software, I don't directly care much about what version of Java an application uses. But if I'm *comparing* competing offerings, and one uses long-obsolete Java 5 whereas another uses up to date technology, then that would be a significant point in favor of the latter. I might even be inclined to suppose that the Java 5 alternative was some kind of legacy product.

> We're trying to port another piece of software from VB6 to this Java 5 platform.
>
> My fear is that we are moving from one outdated platform to another. I would never dream of starting a new project in .net 2.0 for example.

That's not a fear, it's a fact.  Given the opportunity to choose a target Java version for a new, blue-sky effort today, I would never consider Java 5.  I *would* consider Java 8, which, though a bit old, is a long-term support version not scheduled for end-of-life until 2030.  But I would also give strong consideration to some of the more recent versions, especially other LTS releases such as Java 17.

> Our company uses Java 5 for one of our software platforms, the argument being that it is the last free version for windows and Java 5 does everything we need.

"Free" is a business criterion, not a technical one.  If you're selling your software then it affects your profit margin and / or price point, but it's by no means the only thing that does.  Development and maintenance costs are other big ones, and even if you have to pay for Java licenses for your development team, they may favor newer Java versions.  Risk is another criterion -- what if your creaky old Java 5 VM no longer runs on the next version of <OS Of Choice>?

Java 5 probably does do everything you *need*, at least as long as you don't need to use recent versions of any third-party components or frameworks.  Or attract and retain young development talent.  But if you have developers who would use newer Java features effectively given the opportunity to do so, then I expect that newer Java would provide some technical advantages.

> Or are my concerns unfounded?

Your concerns seem somewhat vague, but I think there is some basis for them.

> oh and is Java 5 really still free for commercial use?

Java 5 is no longer distributed (by Oracle) at all.  Your rights with respect to it depend on the license you already have for it, or any license you might be able to negotiate with Oracle now.  I'm not sure to what extent it ever was free for commercial use, but note well that there is a significant difference in that regard between distributing your own software, built for Java 5, and distributing or using a Java 5 VM and library for it to run on.  And note that if your software depends on Java 5 then you will probably need to provide the Java 5 VM and runtime environment, and Oracle might have something to say about that if it's theirs that you would be distributing.